# What's wrong with my SPF record?

Tags: spf

This is my SPF record:

```
v=spf1 a ip4:111.222.333.444 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

I sent a test email to my Gmail address and below are the headers.
I replaced real IP address with 111.222.333.444 and
I replaced server hostname with myserver.example.com

My question is: why headers say that IP address 111.222.333.444 "is neither permitted nor denied"? This IP address is included in SPF record and should be "permitted". It's not a DNS caching problem.

```
Received: from myserver.example.com (static-ip-111-222-333-444.inaddr.example.com
[111.222.333.444])by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id h20si450242faa.105.2011.10.25.23.56.16
(version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
Tue, 25 Oct 2011 23:56:17 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 111.222.333.444 is neither permitted 
nor denied by best guess record for domain of www-data@myserver.example.com) 
client-ip=111.222.333.444;
```

Comment: Is this the SPF record for `myserver.example.com` (i.e. not `example.com`)

Comment: If you want proper troubleshooting on this, you will need to give the domain name you are having trouble with.

Comment: Without **real domainname and IP of sender** all others is useless chat

Answer (score 1):

Without any real data, your record is impossible to validate. Try using some [SPF testing tools](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html) to check for possible problems.

Comment: syneticon-dj, I already tried. The record is valid and this tool didn't find any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Is the record actually returned by queries to the mail domain's DNS with type `TXT`?  Can you provide the output of an nslookup for that name, sanitizing private details?

Google's using "best guess", which means it didn't find the record in your DNS, or couldn't parse what it did find - this is what needs to be fixed.  Your record's syntax is fine, but it's all for naught if the record isn't returned when an SPF client asks for it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you enter your spf record in the DNS zone files,and also chaeck your syntax of spf record it might not be correct,try the link:-spfwizard.com.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Google Workspace which instructs us to add a TXT record to our DNS settings with record name (or host) of `@`. I found that if I added it to the root TXT with no record name my SPF finally started working.

If there is already a root record name, you can add your SPF string on a newline after the existing value.